# How can I change Javascript syntax to higlight objects?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-javascript

I am trying to emulate the Atom JavaScript syntax highlighting in vim, but there are a few things missing.

Namely, I'd like to highlight objects and their chains in red. It'd be dandy if I could also highlight classes in yellow.

Here's what I'm seeing.

**Vim**

[image]

**Atom**

[image]

I am using this enhanced highlighting plugin
https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript

Comment: you probably have to create your own syntax rules, you could start from the mentioned plugin. Note however, that is a magic of its own, and not to be recommended if you not really know Vim (and especially its regular expressions) very well

Answer (score 1):

Try plugin https://github.com/jaxbot/semantic-highlight.vim (see also the [article](https://medium.com/@evnbr/coding-in-color-3a6db2743a1e)).

To install (with Plug plugin manager), set in .vimrc

```
Plug 'jaxbot/semantic-highlight.vim'
```

Default colors fight with colorscheme I use (tender), so I set in  vimrc colors to:

```
let g:semanticTermColors = [3,124,30,32,33,64,66,67,69,99,101,102,103,104,132,133,135,136,137,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,198,200]
```